# Error: 'How do you want to open this file?' prompt when running 'pipenv shell' command in VSCode

Tags: python, cmd, python-venv, pipenv

I am attempting to create a virtual environment using Pipenv. After successfully running the command `pip install pipenv`
in the terminal, I encounter a problem when executing `pipenv shell`. It prompts me with the message "**How do you want to open this file?**" as shown in the screenshot. I have tried selecting both VSCode and Notepad as options, but the issue persists. Additionally, no "**Pipfile**" is being generated in the current directory. What steps can I take to resolve this issue?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDp6P.png)

I have even uninstalled pipenv from both the **CMD** and the **VSCode** terminal, but the issue remains unresolved. I can’t see the **Pipfile** and the **Pipefile.lock**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.